# Temporary error on function in Flutter converting from timestamp to string

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Flutter project with Cloud Firestore as backend.

There is a collection called 'posts'. This collection has documents which include a field called 'post_fecha' from type timestamp.

I would like to show the values for field 'post_fecha' in the format 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'

Therefor I have created a function to convert the received timestamp from Firestore to a date string:

```
  String formatearFecha(Timestamp timestamp){
    var dateFromTimeStamp =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.seconds * 1000);
    return DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm').format(dateFromTimeStamp);
  }
```

The date string is shown correctly:

[image]

But when the a new post is created an error is shown for a second or less, then the app continues running well.

The error is the following:

```
 flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
[        ] flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
[        ] flutter: The getter 'seconds' was called on null.
[   +1 ms] flutter: Receiver: null
[        ] flutter: Tried calling: seconds
[        ] flutter: 
[        ] flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
[        ] flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
[        ] flutter: #1      TimeAgo.formatearFecha (package:flutter_movmap/src/services/time_ago.dart:10:55)
```

The code line mentioned in the error message is:

```
var dateFromTimeStamp =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp.seconds * 1000);
```

I am calling the function as follows:

```
fecha_default = TimeAgo().formatearFecha(listaFiltrada[index].post_fecha);
```

which is inside the StreamBuilder that shows the post on a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to convert firebase `Timestamp` to flutter `Datetime`:

`DateTime toDateTime(Timestamp val) => val?.toDate();`

and this to convert flutter `Datetime` to firebase `Timestamp`

`Timestamp fromDateTime(DateTime val) => val == null ? null : Timestamp.fromDate(val);`